# Data from resolved Promise not loading properly in component view (Angular2, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

I'm fairly new to Angular2 so forgive me if this is a super basic fix.

I'm working through a [tutorial using PokeAPI and Angular2](https://onsen.io/blog/tutorial-how-to-create-pokemon-app-using-angular2-cli/) but trying to deviate from the tutorial to add Pokemon types to the rendered view. However, the data from my PokedexService is not properly loading into my view template like it should.

Full codebase that is producing the error on [Github](https://github.com/mattlayton1986/pokedex-onsen).

As it deviates from the original tutorial, I've updated the Pokemon class to add a `types` property to it:

```
export class Pokemon {
  id: number;
  sprite: string;
  name: string;
  types: [];
}
```

In my `pokedex.service.ts` service file, I've added a new method `getPokemonTypes()` that queries the API for each individual Pokemon's types and returns an array containing either one or two types.

```
getPokemonTypes(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${id}/`)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(details => {
      const types = details.types
      .map(t => {
        return t.type.name;
      });
      return types;
    });
}
```

In my `app.component.ts`, I've called a method `loadMore()` in my `ngOnInit` that **should** load all of the data necessary to render the view when the app initializes. Inside the `loadMore()` method, I've called my `pokedexService`'s `getPokemon()` method and then in that Promise's resolution chain, I've called `getPokemonTypes()` to map Pokemon type values onto my Pokemon object.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemon: Pokemon[] = [];

  isLoading: boolean = false;
  error: boolean = false;

  constructor(private pokedexService: PokedexService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMore();
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.pokedexService.getPokemon(this.pokemon.length, 9)
    .then(pokemon => {
      pokemon = pokemon.map(p => {
        p.imageLoaded = false;

         // Map Pokemon types onto each Pokemon object
        p.types = this.pokedexService.getPokemonTypes(p.id);
        return p;
      });

      this.pokemon = this.pokemon.concat(pokemon);
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.error = false;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.error = true;
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  }
}
```

In my view template (`app.component.html`), I've added a `<div>` to hold the Pokemon types. Currrently the div only renders via `{{p.types}}` just so that I can gain feedback on what is causing the error. For reference, here is the view template:

```
<div class="pokedex">
  <div class="pokedex-pokemon" *ngFor="let p of pokemon">
    <div class="pokedex=pokemon-id">
      #{{p.id}}
    </div>
    <img [ngClass]="{'hidden': !p.imageLoaded}" class="pokedex-pokemon-sprite" (load)="p.imageLoaded = true" [attr.src]="p.sprite" />
    <div class="pokedex-pokemon-name">
      {{p.name | capitalize}}
    </div>
    <div class="pokedex-pokemon-types" *ngIf="!isLoading">
      {{p.types}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I reload the app, the view renders like this: 
[image: Pokedex App -- Error1]
where, instead of rendering the types, it displays `[object Promise]`. I've also tried rendering the view with `{{p.types[0]}}{{p.types[1]}}` since Pokemon.types is an array of types, but when I do that, it doesn't render anything in the view: 
[image: Pokedex App -- Error2]

I've hypothesized that I somehow need to resolve the Promise that is stored in the `types` property, but I thought calling .then() on the returned HTTP promise in the `getPokemonTypes()` method of PokedexService resolved the promise to a value for me.

As a side note, I would ultimately like to render the types in my view like this:

```
<div class="pokedex-pokemon-types">
    <div *ngFor="let t of pokemon.types">
        <div [ngClass]="${t}">{{t}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but thus far I haven't been able to get that to render either. I'm not entirely sure what the proper syntax is for the `[ngClass]` directive to get it to use the Pokemon type name as the class for each div.

Thanks for any help offered! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a result `this.pokedexService.getPokemonTypes(p.id)` a promise? If is, I think you should write something like this:

```
pokemon = pokemon.map(p => {
  p.imageLoaded = false;

    this.pokedexService.getPokemonTypes(p.id)
    .then(types => {
      p.types = types;
      this.pokemon = this.pokemon.concat(p);
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.error = false;      
    });
  });
```

Comment: YES! This fixed it, with one small tweak: 
pokemon = pokemon.map(p => {
        p.imageLoaded = false;
        this.pokedexService.getPokemonTypes(p.id)
        .then(types => {
          p.types = types;
          this.pokemon = this.pokemon.concat(p);
        });
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.error = false;
    })

The this.isLoading and this.error statements have to go outside the getPokemonTypes.then() but inside the main wrapping .then()

Comment: So I'm happy :) Have a nice time with Angular!

Comment: There's only one issue now with my code, since I implemented your suggestion. When I load the page, Pokemon are now loading into the page out of order, instead of in the correct order, as they were before I implemented the change. I've tried playing around with Promise.all() to fix that, but can't get them to load in p.id order -- they just load in the order their promise resolves.

Comment: Hm, maybe you should sort an array from code with sort() metod after every concat()?  It's rather quick fix, not a first-class solution, but it should help.